# Create query between ManyToMany relationship models in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

```
class Review(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(UserDetail)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vote_content = models.FloatField()
    vote_knowledge = models.FloatField()
    vote_assignment = models.FloatField()
    vote_classroom = models.FloatField()
    vote_instructor = models.FloatField()

class UserDetail(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    studentlist = models.ManyToManyField(UserDetail, related_name='course_studentlist', blank=True)
    reviewlist = models.ManyToManyField(Review,related_name='course_reviewlist', blank=True)
    ...
```

In the above model structure, the Course model has a relationship with UserDetail and Review with ManyToMany.

The review is based on the average of the 5 votes. (content, knowledge etc.)

A review of a course is the average of the votes of the students who take the course.

I would like to make a search and sort according to Course's review, for example, list bigger than 3 votes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and probably the cleanest solution is to create additional field for storing average score in `Review` and calculate it on `save()`.

Is there a reason why you keep course reviews as m2m field? Do you allow the same review, with the same text etc. to be used in many courses? Maybe you need `ForeignKey` in this case. Then you could just do:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    vote_avg = models.FloatField()
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course')
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.voce_avg = (self.vote_content + ...) / 5
        super(Review, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def foo():
    return Course.objects.prefetch_related('review_set').annotate(
        avg_reviews=Avg('review__vote_avg')
    ).filter(avg_reviews__gt=3).order_by('avg_reviews')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Course.objects.annotate(reviews_count=Count('reviewlist')).filter(reviews_count__gt=3)
```